# document.open does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have the following javascript code, I tried to test it in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, they all working fine, but on Safari, it generates error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x.document')", any idea on how to resolve it? Thanks.

```
var x = window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write('hello world');
x.document.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Chrome. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable popup windows in Safari. Go to `Preferences > Security > Block pop-up windows` for this to work in Safari. Otherwise, Safari does not allow you to reference a document within a blocked window.